# How can you improve computation time when predicting KNN Imputation?

Tags: performance, r-caret, knn, imputation

I feel like my run time is extremely slow for my data set, this is the code:

```
    library(caret)
    library(data.table)
    knnImputeValues <- preProcess(mainData[trainingRows, imputeColumns], method = c("zv", "knnImpute"))
    knnTransformed <- predict(knnImputeValues, mainData[ 1:1000, imputeColumns])
```

the PreProcess into knnImputeValues run's fairly quickly, however the predict function takes a tremendous amount of time.  When I calculated it on a subset of the data this was the result:

```
testtime <- system.time(knnTransformed <- predict(knnImputeValues, mainData[ 1:15000, imputeColumns
testtime

user     969.78
system   38.70 
elapsed  1010.72
```

Additionally, it should be noted that caret preprocess uses "RANN".

Now my full dataset is:

```
 str(mainData[ , imputeColumns])
'data.frame':   1809032 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ V1: int  3 5 5 4 4 4 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1000000","1500000",..: 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ V3: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V4: int  2 5 5 12 4 5 11 8 7 8 ...
 $ V5: int  2 0 0 2 0 0 1 3 2 8 ...
 $ V6: int  648 489 489 472 472 472 497 642 696 696 ...
 $ V7: Factor w/ 4 levels "","N","U","Y": 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V8: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ V9: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V10: Factor w/ 56 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 45 19 19 19 19 19 19 46 46 46 ...
 $ V11: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V12: num  2 5 5 12 4 5 11 8 7 8 ...
 $ V13: num  2 0 0 2 0 0 1 3 2 8 ...
 $ V14: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ V15: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ V16: num  657 756 756 756 756 ...
```

So is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this typical for how long it will take to run this? If you back of the envelop extrapolate (which I know isn't entire accurate) you'd get what 33 days?

Also it looks like system time is very low and user time is very high, is that normal?

My computer is a laptop, with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40Ghz processor.

Additionally would this improve the runtime of the predict function?

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel()
```

I tried it, and it didn't seem to make a difference other than all the processors looked more active in my task manager.

**FOCUSED QUESTION: I'm using Caret package to do KNN Imputation on 1.8 Million Rows, the way I'm currently doing it will take over a month to run, how do I write this in such a way that I could do it in a much faster amount of time(if possible)?**

Thank you for any help provided. And the answer might very well be "that's how long it takes don't bother" I just want to rule out any possible mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the packages you're using with your post. kNN relies on distance calculations which are O(n^2). You have 1.8M rows... there are various approaches you could use, such as approximate kNN and canopies. You need to clarify your question though for a more specific answer.

Comment: I added what I hope to be a clearer question, thanks for your reply.  Is approximate knn or canopies available to caret preprocess?  Also is 1000 seconds to do 15,000 rows seem right to you?

Comment: One standard way to improve KNN performance is to embed your reference points into a search tree (I'd recommend the VPS-tree data structure, because it's far less prone to the dimensionality curse problem) reducing the optimal neighbourhood search complexity. That being said, I would recommend against KNN for missing data imputation. You'd better train a denoising autoencoder or an RBM. It will take you a day to train the thing to a decent level. The imputation itself will work pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed this up via the `imputation` package and use of canopies which can be installed from [Github](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation):

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++0x")
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation")
```

Canopies use a cheap distance metric--in this case distance from the data mean vector--to get approximate neighbors. In general, we wish to keep the canopies each sized < 100k so for 1.8M rows, we'll use 20 canopies:

```
library("imputation")
to_impute <- mainData[trainingRows, imputeColumns] ## OP undefined
imputed <- kNN_impute(to_impute, k= 10, q= 2, verbose= TRUE, 
                      parallel= TRUE, n_canopies= 20)
```

#### NOTE:

The imputation package **requires** numeric data inputs. You have several factor variables in your `str` output. They will cause this to fail.

You'll also get some mean vector imputation if you have fulling missing rows.

```
# note this example data is too small for canopies to be useful
# meant solely to illustrate
set.seed(2143L)
x1 <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100, 10)
x1[sample(1:1000, size= 50, replace= FALSE)] <- NA
x_imp <- kNN_impute(x1, k=5, q=2, n_canopies= 10)
sum(is.na(x_imp[[1]])) # 0

# with fully missing rows
x2 <- x1; x2[5,] <- NA
x_imp <- kNN_impute(x2, k=5, q=2, n_canopies= 10)
[1] "Computing canopies kNN solution provided within canopies"
[1] "Canopies complete... calculating kNN."
row(s) 1 are entirely missing. 
                     These row(s)' values will be imputed to column means.
Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Rows with entirely missing values imputed to column means.
```

Comment: I've been running the KNNimputer in python on a dataset of size [603281,  670] and it has been running continuously for two weeks now. Is it safe to assume it is still going or is it stuck in which case I should stop it and try an alternative solution? 

All the datatypes are correct and made sure the dataset is appropriate for the imputed before running. It is running in a docker container on a dedicated windows server.